# Yahoo oauth issue with hybridauth

Tags: php, oauth, yahoo, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I'm using example with Yahoo oauth from hybridauth http://oyanix.com/opensource/hybridauth/social_hub/login.php but it doesn't work with the following message "Original error message: User id request failed! Yahoo returned an invalid response."

How it could be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution how to fix it from hybridauth https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/174#issuecomment-38408597